# 95 percentile for failure frequency with Poisson process

Tags: gamma-distribution, reliability, poisson-process, failure-rate

I am trying to recreate the stats for 'failure frequency' - in this case the 95 percentile - shown in the attached images below.

For one set of failure data there are 27 failures over a cumulative 42889 years of operation. the Expected Value is 6.3e-4 and the shown 95% upper limit is 8.4e-4 in terms of failure frequency.

I get close if I model an inverse Poisson distribution (for the 95% CDF). But I cannot reproduce the results using what looks like the Gamma distribution PDF proposed.

See linked images:

Image from Dutch Handbook Appendix A (translated to English)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMPtF.png)

Image from Dutch Handbook Appendix A (translated to English)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4GMd.png)

Any feedback or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Poisson process with a rate parameter of $8.411623\times 10^{-4}$ per year (so rounding to `8.4e-4`)

then the probability you see at least $27$ occurrences in $42889$ years can be found using the Gamma distribution cumulative distribution function to be $95\%$

In R

```
> pgamma(42889, 27, 8.411623e-4)
[1] 0.95
```

Comment: Many Thx.
As a follow up question, to me the logic of using this approach to establish the 95%ile seems not quite correct as it implies a fractional number of failures for the time period. E.g. for the above rate parameter I calculate 36.08 failures.

Rather I had assumed that the best way to calculate the 95%ile was to use the Poisson CDF based on a mean (or expected value) of 27, which results in 36 for the 95%ile, and estimate the failure rate from 36 over the same time period. Similar but not same result due to the difference between the discrete vs continuous distribution assumption.

Comment: @akarich73  You are saying $42889 \times 8.411623\times 10^{-4} \approx 36.07661$ is not an integer.  But the parameter of a Poisson distribution does not need to be an integer and with that parameter the probability of getting strictly fewer than $27$ observations is $0.05$: with R `ppois(26,36.07661)` gives `0.04999997`.

Comment: If instead you used `qpois(0.95,27)` to get `36` you would hit the problem that `ppois(36,27)` gives `0.9612017` which is too high.  You would still have the Poisson-Gamma equivalence:  `ppois(26,36)` gives `0.0512685` while `pgamma(42889,27,36/42889)` gives `0.9487315` and these add up to $1$ but would be slightly the wrong side of $95\%$.  It is only a slight change and $\frac{36}{42889} \approx 8.393761\times 10^{-4}$ which also rounds to $8.4\times 10^{-4}$.  But this is the wrong way of looking at this: if you saw $0$ failures, then $0$ would also be your top figure, and that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think the understanding that the Poisson distribution is discrete, but the time (here time is 42889 hours worth) between events is continuous and follows an Exponential Distribution. A good discussion can be found here on the relationship Poisson to: Exponential, Gamma, and Chi Squared:
https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue116/relbasics116.htm

I get a slightly different (higher) estimate for the 95% upper bound for the failure rate (lambda) 8.6815*E-4, that suggests ~ 37 vs 36. I think the issue is in the Poisson-Gamma equivalence assumptions. X= Lambda x T follows the Gamma distribution X ~ Gamma(r+1,1) where r is the number of failures. Note the "r+1". The Chi Squared distribution is a special case of the Gamma distribution and is commonly used to estimate the bounds for Poisson Rates. Lambda 95% upper bound = ChiSq (0.05,2(r+1)) /2T. (Excel function=CHISQ.INV.RT(0.05,2(27+1))/2 =37.234 so 37.  The 95% upper bound for Lambda=37.234/42889 =8.68E-4 . I hope this helps.

Comment: +1.  Thank you for the correction.  BTW, a "discreet" distribution is one that doesn't reveal your name ;-).